# Network traffic monitoring in Solaris

Tags: solaris

How can I capture and **keep** a log of network traffic on a Solaris 11 box? I can use vnStat on Linux but is there a solution for Solaris?

Comment: You might want something like [snoop](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-0211/6m6nc677k/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

The vnStat homepage ( http://humdi.net/vnstat/ ) lists the following as 'Similar Programs', under their 'Links' heading:

- ntop
- darkstat
- MRTG
- bwm-ng
- iftop
- IPTraf

I've had experience with IPTraf (ages ago), but it still works fairly well. And it looks like a majority of them are able to be compiled and packaged for Solaris 11. http://www.unixpackages.com/ has a subscription service that will do that for you, should you want to avail yourself of their services. Otherwise, `configure; make; make install` away!

Comment: If the package is available for Solaris 11 at sunfreeware, it at least means you can compile and run it for Solaris 11.  Unfortunately, despite the name of the website, software downloads are no longer freely available from the maintainers of that site.

Comment: True: it's been a long time since I used that site. It looks like Mr. Christensen moved most of the package information to http://www.unixpackages.com/ ... and it still looks like they have a number of the referenced packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use snoop on all versions of Solaris, but since you note v11, you can also easily install wireshark or use the cmdline version tshark.

pkg add diagnostic/wireshark

You also may want to check out this article on [Advanced Network Monitoring Using Oracle Solaris 11 Tools](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-admin/sol-adv-network-monitoring-2008573.html) which shows some Solaris 11 specific commands including how to have some output be in a format read by gnuplot.

In addition, you want to see if there are any other tools, including some of those mentioned by Thomas N. available in the Solaris 11 support or GA repos.